# get authetication in google api browser but gargle permission fails

Tags: r, google-drive-api, gargle

I am using googledrive to download directly from my drive folders, I am getting now this error

since i was getting this error Show in New Window

> Error in `gargle_abort_request_failed()`:
> ! Client error: (403) Forbidden
> Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient
> authentication scopes.
> • domain: global
> • reason: insufficientPermissions
> • message: Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient
> authentication scopes.

Backtrace:

1. googledrive::drive_ls(...)
2. googledrive:::as_parent(path)
3. googledrive:::as_dribble.drive_id(d)
4. googledrive::drive_get(id = x)
5. purrr::map(as_id(id), get_one_file_id)
6. googledrive (local) .f(.x[[i]], ...)
7. gargle::response_process(response)
8. gargle:::gargle_abort_request_failed(error_message(resp), resp)
   Error in gargle_abort_request_failed(error_message(resp), resp) :

I used `gs4_deauth()` and then `gs4_auth()` to open the google api and get authentified again... I am still getting the same error, what should I do?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

Means that the access token that was used to make this request was not created with the proper scopes.  Im not sure which method you are using exactly but

The [file.export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) method requires one of the following scopes

[image]

The [file.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) method requires one of the following scopes

[image]

You need to request authorization of the user with the proper consent scope

Answer (score -1):

I received this same error when updating some packages.  I was able to resolve by entering "0" at this prompt when starting it up from a fresh R session.  Even though my account was listed under option "1", entering "0" allowed me to refresh it somehow.

```
The googlesheets4 package is requesting access to your Google account.
Select a pre-authorised account or enter '0' to obtain a new token.
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to cancel.
```